# CSS - Can't include .ttf file

Tags: css, font-face

I want to use **fontlero** font for my page and I downloaded the .ttf file. And I include it in my main CSS but this gave me some other font. here is my css code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: FONTLERO;
src: url(fonts/FONTLERO.TTF);
}

.customfont { 
font-family: "FONTLERO";
src: url('../fonts/FONTLERO.TTF') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/FONTLERO.TTF') format('opentype');
}

.story h1 {
font-family: FONTLERO;
font-size: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Path should be inside the CSS folder like below

```
css/fonts/FONTLERO.TTF
```